# Suggestions for Digital Logic Design laboratory projects ?

Tags: design, digital-logic

What are some simple Digital Design projects that I can make using basic IC's in the laboratory like Logic gates, Counters, registers, mux/demux ... etc?

Comment: Try to make the question more specific, for instance addressing a specific type of circuits that you would like to teach (such as sequential logic)

Comment: Yes of course, my bad .. I'll write another question with specific details and information.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very broad question:

- you can use timers (555) as multivibrators to make traffic lights,
- you can use combinational and sequential logic to make sequence detectors or
- you can play with displays (LED and LCD),
- you can create event counters with photoresistors or buttons...